# JmxResource published with simplejmx does not appear in JConsole

Tags: java, spring, jmx, jconsole, simplejmx

I am using `simplejmx` to publish my `JMX Resources`.

I have got `jmx-config.xml`

```
<bean id="beanPublisher" class="com.j256.simplejmx.spring.BeanPublisher">
    <property name="jmxServer" ref="jmxServer" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmxServer" class="com.j256.simplejmx.server.JmxServer"
    init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="registryPort" value="8123" />
</bean>
```

I am starting my `JBoss` application, everything is ok:

```
15:20:11,860 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-8) Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1be30160: defining beans [...,beanPublisher,jmxServer,...]; root of factory hierarchy
```

I created a simply class.

```
package com.mypckg.jmx;

import com.j256.simplejmx.common.JmxAttributeField;
import com.j256.simplejmx.common.JmxResource;

@JmxResource(description = "Blah1", domainName = "Blah2", beanName = "Blah3")
public class DummyJMX {

    @JmxAttributeField(description = "Blah4")
    private int var = 3;
}
```

I am starting `JConsole`, I am choosing `JBoss` application and I am going to `MBeans`. That is what I see:

[image]
*

Probably, my `DummyJMX` class has not been published (or I just cannot find it).

About which step I forgot?

Thank you in advance

---

**EDIT :**

[image]

---

**EDIT :**

@Andrei Stefan

An error which I got using your link:

[image]

@Gray

An error which I got using `localhost:8123`:

[image]

Comment: I haven't used j256 jmx server, but since there is a port that's being specified at server creation, shouldn't you connect with JConsole to something else other than JBoss?

Comment: @AndreiStefan I am even almost sure, that you are right, but...when my JBoss Server is down, I can choose 2 things in JConsole, when I run my server, there is only one more. I added a screenshot to my question.

Comment: Don't choose a Local Process, but try with a Remote Process. Use this as a JMX URL: service:jmx:rmi://jndi/rmi://localhost:8123/jmxrmi

Comment: Hi, I tried it but it does not work. I edited my post and I pasted a printscreen. I checked [Using JConsole](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) syntax of this URL and it looks good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I am connected to my `JMX Beans` using `JConsole`.

Probably, I did something wrong in the beginning of my work with `simplejmx`.

I have not changed a lot of things. I kept `jmx-config` file and I still use version `1.8` of `simplejmx`.

I can easily connect to this bean `locally` - I have no idea why I was not able to do that earlier. Could you tell me, why in your opinion it should not be a `local process`?

Below, you can see that my `JMX Bean` appears in `JConsole`:

[image]

Comment: It depends. Briefly, my question was: `what to do to make it works`. Finally, it works as a local process and your answers suggested to use remote one. I cannot figure out why it did not work in the beginning. If you have got any idea, what could be a proper answer here, do not hesitate to answer my question.

Comment: My answer specifically says that it won't show up as a local process.  It's a different registration mechanism.  As my answer states, you should use the platform mbean server if you want it to be seen locally.

Answer (score 0):

> Probably, my DummyJMX class has not been published (or I just cannot find it).

When you are using the `registryPort` configuration for `JmxServer` then it will not show up in the "Local Process" list under Jconsole.  It will be able to be accessed as a "Remote Process" with `localhost:8123`.  If you are on a Linux box, you might use `netstat -an | grep LISTEN` to see what ports your application is listening on.  If you don't see 8123 in the list then maybe it already has a RMI server configured?

If you want to use the platform mbean-server which *does* show up as a local process then use the new setter or constructor in version 1.9 which was released recently (4/2014).  Unfortunately, SimpleJMX cannot programmatically register itself so it shows up in the process list -- that's not code that the JVM exports.

```
<bean id="jmxServer" class="com.j256.simplejmx.server.JmxServer"
    init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="usePlatformMBeanServer" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Hi, I would like to keep it in this way. I tried `localhost:8123` but it gives me an error. I edited my post.

Comment: when I am trying with `usePlatformMBeanServer` it gives me an error `[...] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name "beanPublisher" [...] Bean property 'setUsePlatformMBeanServer' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?` . I changed `sipmle jmx` version to `1.9`

Comment: I don't understand this @GirlyGirl.  The code I posted works for me.  Are you sure you are using 1.9?  Note that the property is _not_ `setUsePlatformMBeanServer` but is instead `usePlatformMBeanServer`.  Is that the problem?

Comment: I cannot understand, why I pasted here `setUsePlatformMBeanServer`. I used your piece of code. An error is of course about field `usePlatformMBeanServer` . `Bean property 'usePlatformMBeanServer' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?` I checked directory `\standalone\deployments\myproject.war\WEB-INF\lib` and I can see 2 libs: `simplejmx-1.8` and `simplejmx-1.9` . I did `Project clean` and also `Maven clean` in Eclipse. No changes, still both versions exist in lib directory.

Comment: I have got a question: Is version `1.9` dependent on `1.8`? If not, probably I have got some problems with `Maven`. I run my server and I did `full publish`. After that, I stopped it and I removed manually version `1.8` from deployed `war`. I run my server once again and now it works. Anyhow, I would like to use your lib in this way: `<property name="registryPort" value="8123" />` so I will be working on it.

Comment: 1.9 is certainly not dependent on 1.8.  Are you depending on another package that depends on 1.8?  Maybe you are missing an exclusion @GirlyGirl.

Comment: To be honest, I have no idea what was wrong. I will just keep version `1.8`.

Comment: You'll need 1.9 for the `usePlatformMBeanServer` @GirlyGirl.

Comment: I will not use it. I am using now `1.8` with `registryPort` and now it works. I can easily access my `JMX Beans` using local process.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following url in JConsole, with Remote Process option: `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:8123/jmxrmi`

It's a bit different than what I provided in the comments.

Comment: Thank you. It gives the same error. Do you think it could be a problem with `/`? I am working on Windows if it changes something.

Comment: The URL I provided works for me in a simple Spring project that uses your exact code and configuration. I can see the bean in JConsole, after I added this to my configuration: `<bean id="dummy" class="com.mypckg.jmx.DummyJMX" />` (I assumed you have this somewhere in your config).

Comment: In, my code, this bean `dummy` is commented. I just want to set up my server and verify, if I am able to connect with `JConsole`.

Comment: I uncommented it. Still, I cannot connect with `JConsole`. Two, not really smart questions: 1. Can it be problem with `proxy`? 2. Should I provide any `username/password` ? In documentation is written to use it only in a specyfic case.

Comment: Now I'm thinking it can be something related to JBoss... but not sure what. You could try the same code and configuration in a standalone project, not .war and outside JBoss.

Comment: What JBoss version are you using?

Comment: Try another thing: uncomment the dummy bean in your code, replackage and redeploy your .war and then connect with JConsole to the JBoss JMX service.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50670/discussion-between-girly-girl-and-andrei-stefan)